Can I wire the PnP wire to ground?
I need to wire a precision switch with the following diagram.
There is an LED in the switch.
Ça I just wire the black wire to ground it I don't need the signal and just want the led working when the switch is triggered?


No, you can't ground the black wire, it will damage the output.
If you don't need the black wire, leave it unconnected.
